# Saving shapes on top of large images

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory, save-image

I'm creating somekind of 2D image editor in Android and I have the big problem of big files don't fit in memory.

I need to zoom in/out the image put some shapes and then save it.

My question is:

How can I load the image and save it without getting out of memory?
I've been reading about bitmapregiondecode and the sample technic but there's must be another solution. How can I save the image if I always use regiondecode?

The images need good detail quality because it's architectural images... and the lines must be well defined.

I'm new to this, help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note two things while dealing with images:

tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bit);

clone the bitmap which you are using for zoom and other operations but wont use the original because it looses its clarity when you save;

when done with bitmap give
bit.recycle();
to release the memory space